# animating panorama control when set pragmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, panorama-control

I'm using

```
panoramaControl.DefaultItem = panoramaControl.Items[index];
```

to navigate the panorama control from one to another, but sliding effect is not seen in this case. what can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a limitation of the platform.

You should also note how setting the default item changes the panorama parallax background (and/or header).